# Contrapartida à hint do comentário no campo resposta

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, respostas, comentários

Reparei no site móvel que o campo para comentários tem uma *hint*:

> Use comentários para pedir mais informações ou sugerir melhorias. Evite responder perguntas em comentários.

E o campo para resposta não possui a *hint* inversa "não usar a resposta para comentários".

Mas poderia ter. Por que não tem? Foi estudado e não é vantajoso? Quero crer que é uma medida pequena e simples que pode dar algum resultado para os enganos dos novatos.

O site tem muitos outros problemas, esta é só uma coisa meio óbvia que eu acabei reparando e achei por bem levantar.

Comment: _"O site tem muitos outros problemas"_ - poderia citá-los?

Comment: @CypherPotato Não me referia a ter problemas não-citados, e sim aos problemas que a SE tem, em relação à comunidade do site, a como trata a comunidade, aos problemas do processo de responder perguntas e manter a qualidade do site que não são tratados e são discutidos em outras perguntas aqui do meta, esse tipo de problema. Perto desses um acréscimo de hint pode parecer irrelevante, por isso citei os outros problemas.

Comment: @Piovezan Eu concordo que pode parecer irrelevante mas também acho que mais vale resolver alguma coisa, mesmo que insignificante, do que não resolver nada. Logo acho uma questão pertinente

Comment: @Piovezan sua foto de perfil por acaso é uma unidade de colônia do Sid Meier's Civilization?

Comment: @riki481 Sim, como diz o meu perfil. Saudosista pouco :)

Comment: @Piovezan jogo até hoje o primeiro da franquia, é muito bom e funciona em qualquer PC